# Cannot install Angular AoT compiler (ngc) on windows 7

Tags: angular

I cannot install ngc,

I am starting from the quickstart github project

```
npm install

...

| | +-- stringstream@0.0.5
| | +-- tough-cookie@2.3.2
| | | `-- punycode@1.4.1
| | +-- tunnel-agent@0.4.3
| | `-- uuid@3.0.1
| `-- semver@5.3.0
`-- zone.js@0.6.26

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

then I do

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli @angular/platform-server --save

+-- @angular/compiler-cli@2.2.4
| `-- @angular/tsc-wrapped@0.3.0
|   `-- tsickle@0.1.7
|     +-- source-map@0.4.4
|     | `-- amdefine@1.0.1
|     `-- source-map-support@0.3.3
|       `-- source-map@0.1.32
`-- @angular/platform-server@2.2.4
  `-- parse5@2.2.3

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

but I cannot run ngc

```
D:\WORK\ANGULAR\tutorial\quickstart-master>ngc
'ngc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

there is no .bin folder in node_modules either

Comment: Have you tried something like this `"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json`? Otherwise you have to add ngc to Environment Variables

Comment: as mentioned, there is no .bin folder

Comment: Sorry, i omitted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finaly managed to make it work, deleted node_modules and reinstalled everything

Answer (score 0):

I took the started project from [Minko Gechev Angular Seed AOT](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) on GitHub.  I followed the install instructions, and cloned the git repository.  I ignored the fsevent warnings as they do not cause any problems.

Following the directions on this page gave me the results.  I do tend to run my npm install and other simialr commands with the --msvs-version and the year of my Visual Studio, which is 2015 (--msvs-version=2015).

```
 ~/Development/aot (master)
$ which ngc
<deleted my start path>  node_modules/.bin/ngc
```

The ngc is in the .bin for me and all I did was follow the installation instructions, including installing and using Yarn.

Comment: I mentioned windows 7 , not linux...btw I use the official angular2 seed, so it should work,I'll try to find some angular contact or forum to ask them, it should be working

Comment: I used Windows 7 as you indicated but did all the work using GIT bash which works well.

Comment: just tried with git cmd, still no .bin folder...I asked a collegue to try on his pc, maybe there is something wrong on my machine

Comment: I do find the Git Bash to work better than the command with some installs in the past.  I also normally add --msvs-version=2015 (I use Visual Studio 2015 Community) to the npm command line (npm install --msvs-version=2015) to help with some components that end up getting compiled.

Comment: ok I finaly managed to make it work, deleted node_modules and reinstalled everything